# Android - Kotlin Handler cancel postDelayed task

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the code that is attached below. The purpose is just to test canceling the scheduled task created with Handler. Inside the `onCreate` function I defined `runnable`, which I passed as an argument to both `schedule` and `cancel` function. My goal is to schedule the function, but cancel it before it comes to its execution. I am trying to cancel the scheduled task with `removeCallbacks` function. I also did try using function `removeCallbacksAndMessages` passing `null` as an argument, as well as passing Integer value as a token, which I passed as well inside the `postDelay` function. None of the mentioned did not cancelled the scheduled `task` function. Many thanks for any of your help.

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val runnable = Runnable {
            task()
        }
        this.schedule(runnable)
        this.cancelSchedule(runnable)
    }

    fun schedule(runable: Runnable) {
        Log.d("Schedule", "schedule")
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(runable, 5000)
    }

    fun cancelSchedule(runable: Runnable) {
        Log.d("Cancel", "cancele")
        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).removeCallbacksAndMessages(runable)
    }

    fun task(){
        Log.d("TASK", "run")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Handler instance has its own message queue. Since you keep creating new Handlers in both your `schedule` and `cancelSchedule` functions, you are not working with the same queue.

You need a single Handler instance to be able to do this, so you should store it in a property.

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val runnable = Runnable {
            task()
        }
        this.schedule(runnable)
        this.cancelSchedule(runnable)
    }

    fun schedule(runable: Runnable) {
        Log.d("Schedule", "schedule")
        handler.postDelayed(runable, 5000)
    }

    fun cancelSchedule(runable: Runnable) {
        Log.d("Cancel", "cancele")
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(runable)
    }

    fun task(){
        Log.d("TASK", "run")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose, or why every Handler has its own message queue? I tought that when passing Looper.getMainLooper() the tasks are pushed to the same message queue, so they could be removed from any Handler passed the same "loop"/message queue? Many thanks for help. Your solution worked anyway. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why shouldn't you be allowed to create more than one message queue? It's kind of like asking why you're allowed to create more than one List instead of there only being a single List for the whole app to handle everything. That would be very limiting for code organization/encapsulation and what you could do with it.

Comment: Ok I got it. I kinda tought that the task is being put to some one and only (main) event loop. In this case all the created message queues must be executed by any other(main) event loop?

Comment: There’s one main loop, but it can have many queues. I guess in a way, each Handler is a sub-queue of a Looper’s queue. Also, you don’t have to use the main looper for a Handler. You can create Loopers that run on another thread.